# Bash - Check directory for files against list of partial file names

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts

I have a server which receives a file per client each day into a directory. The filenames are constructed as follows:

```
uuid_datestring_other-data
```

For example:

```
d6f60016-0011-49c4-8fca-e2b3496ad5a7_20160204_023-ERROR
```

- `uuid` is a standard format uuid.
- `datestring` is the output from `date +%Y%m%d`.
- `other-data` is variable in length but will never contain an underscore.

I have a file of the format:

```
#
d6f60016-0011-49c4-8fca-e2b3496ad5a7    client1
d5873483-5b98-4895-ab09-9891d80a13da    client2
be0ed6a6-e73a-4f33-b755-47226ff22401    another_client
...
```

I need to check that every uuid listed in the file has a corresponding file in the directory, using bash.

I've got this far, but feel like I'm coming from the wrong direction by using an if statement, and that I need to loop through the files in the source directory.

The source_directory and uuid_list variables have been assigned earlier in the script:

```
# Check the entries in the file list

while read -r uuid name; do
# Ignore comment lines
   [[ $uuid = \#* ]] && continue
   if [[ -f "${source_directory}/${uuid}*" ]]
   then
      echo "File for ${name} has arrived"
   else
      echo "PANIC! - No File for ${name}"
   fi
done < "${uuid_list}"
```

How should I check that the files in my list exist in the directory? I'd like to use bash functionality as far as possible, but am not against using commands if need be.

Comment: Python? And is the server directory "flat"?

Comment: Yes it's flat, no sub-directories. I'd rather stick with just bash if possible.

Comment: Ok, I won't post.

Comment: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/79301/70524, http://stackoverflow.com/q/6363441/2072269

Comment: I don't really see what's wrong with what you have. You will need to loop through either the UUIDs or the files, why would one loop be better than the other?

Comment: @terdon the problem being `[[ -f ... ]]` doesn't really accept wildcards.

Comment: I just noticed I posted a solution almost identical to what you have already... thought you were looping through the files. I guess you can't do much better than what you're doing already, what's the concern exactly?

Comment: @muru ah, yes, that's true. The OP seemed to want a different logic though and I don't see anything wrong with the approach's logic.

Comment: Undeleted my answer in case it's conciseness what you're after, but really the method used is not much better than what you currently have; what you currently have, beside the implementation, is probably the most effective method already .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Walk over the files, create an associative array over the uuids contained in their names (I used parameter expansion to extract the uuid). The, read the list, check the associative array for each uuid and report whether the file was recorded or not.

```
#!/bin/bash
uuid_list=...

declare -A file_for
for file in *_*_* ; do
    uuid=${file%%_*}
    file_for[$uuid]=1
done

while read -r uuid name ; do
    [[ $uuid = \#* ]] && continue
    if [[ ${file_for[$uuid]} ]] ; then
        echo "File for $name has arrived."
    else
        echo "File for $name missing!"
    fi
done < "$uuid_list"
```

Comment: Nice (+1), but why is this better than what the OP was doing? You seem to be doing the same basic thing but in two steps instead of one.

Comment: @terdon: The main difference is this works :-) The wildcard expansion is done just once, not every time you read a line from the list, which might be faster, too.

Comment: Yes, that's an important difference. Fair enough :)

Comment: This is marvellous thank-you, got my +1. Is there any way of including the path to the directory which holds the files? I know I can `cd` into the directory within the script, but just wondered for the sake of gaining knowledge.

Comment: @Arronical: It's possible, but you'll have to remove the path from the string, possible with `file=${file##*/}`.

Comment: +1 This requires just one scan of the directory, so it's going to speed things up if you have lots of files to check.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a more "bashy" and concise approach:

```
#!/bin/bash

## Read the UUIDs into the array 'uuids'. Using awk
## lets us both skip comments and only keep the UUID
mapfile -t uuids < <(awk '!/^\s*#/{print $1}' uuids.txt)

## Iterate over each UUID
for uuid in ${uuids[@]}; do
        ## Set the special array $_ (the positional parameters: $1, $2 etc)
        ## to the glob matching the UUID. This will be all file/directory
        ## names that start with this UUID.
        set -- "${source_directory}"/"${uuid}"*
        ## If no files matched the glob, no file named $1 will exist
        [[ -e "$1" ]] && echo "YES : $1" || echo  "PANIC $uuid" 
done
```

Note that while the above is pretty and will work fine for a few files, its speed depends on the number of UUIDs and will be *very* slow if you need to process many. If that is the case, either use @choroba's solution or, for something truly fast, avoid the shell and call `perl`:

```
#!/bin/bash

source_directory="."
perl -lne 'BEGIN{
            opendir(D,"'"$source_directory"'"); 
            foreach(readdir(D)){ /((.+?)_.*)/; $f{$2}=$1; }
           } 
           s/\s.*//; $f{$_} ? print "YES: $f{$_}" : print "PANIC: $_"' uuids.txt
```

Just to illustrate the time differences, I tested my bash approach, choroba's and my perl on a file with 20000 UUIDs of which 18001 had a corresponding file name. Note that each test was run by redirecting the script's output to `/dev/null`.

1. My bash (~3.5 min)

   ```
   real   3m39.775s
   user   1m26.083s
   sys    2m13.400s
   ```
2. Choroba's (bash, ~0.7 sec)

   ```
   real   0m0.732s
   user   0m0.697s
   sys    0m0.037s
   ```
3. My perl (~0.1 sec):

   ```
   real   0m0.100s
   user   0m0.093s
   sys    0m0.013s
   ```

Comment: +1 for a fantastically concise method, this would have to be executed from within the directory containing the files. I know I can `cd` into the directory in the script, but is there a method whereby the file path could be included in the search?

Comment: @Arronical sure, see updated answer. You can use `${source_directory}` just like you were doing in your script.

Comment: Or use `"$2"` and pass it to the script as a second argument.

Comment: Check that this runs fast enough for your purposes-- it would be faster to do it with a single directory scan, instead of lots of file lookups like this.

Comment: @alexis I don't see what you mean by " pass it to the script as a second argument". Pass what? The `$source_dir`? Why 2nd argument? There's no `$1` here. Also, the OP states in the question that this is just a part of a larger script and the `${source_directory}` is defined earlier. As for speed, this will be pretty fast. The limiting factor will be the number of uuids, not the number of target files. Are you thinking of storing all directory names as keys in an associative array and then querying it for each uuid?

Comment: Oops, right, there's no `$1`-- I'd assumed `uuid.txt` is passed on the command line. As `$2`, then.

Comment: Re performance: The way I'd read the question, the number of uuids and the number of files are probably roughly equal; but really both quantities matter. In your solution, each uuid triggers a directory scan and each scan has runtime that depends on the size of the directory. If there's more than a couple uuid's, yes I'd go with storing filenames (just the uuid part) in an assoc array if performance is a problem. Except I'd do it in python, which the OP isn't interested in...

Comment: @alexis yes, you're quite right. I did some testing and this becomes _very_ slow if the number of UUIDs/files increases. I added a perl approach (which can be run as a one liner from within th bash script, so technically, still bash if you're open to some creative naming) which is far faster.

Comment: It also takes some creative naming to call that a one-liner  :-)

Comment: Nice that you timed it, btw. Always nice when someone takes the trouble to.

Answer (score 3):

This is pure Bash (i.e. no external commands), and it's the most coincise approach that I can think of.

*But* performance-wise is really not much better than what you currently have.

It will read each line from `path/to/file`; for each line, it will store the first field in `$uuid` and prints a message if a file matching the pattern `path/to/directory/$uuid*` is *not* found:

```
#! /bin/bash
[ -z "$2" ] && printf 'Not enough arguments.\n' && exit

while read uuid; do
    [ ! -f "$2/$uuid"* ] && printf '%s missing in %s\n' "$uuid" "$2"
done <"$1"
```

Call it with `path/to/script path/to/file path/to/directory`.

Sample output using the sample input file in the question on a test directory hierarchy containing the sample file in the question:

```
% tree
.
├── path
│   └── to
│       ├── directory
│       │   └── d6f60016-0011-49c4-8fca-e2b3496ad5a7_20160204_023-ERROR
│       └── file
└── script.sh

3 directories, 3 files
% ./script.sh path/to/file path/to/directory
d5873483-5b98-4895-ab09-9891d80a13da* missing in path/to/directory
be0ed6a6-e73a-4f33-b755-47226ff22401* missing in path/to/directory
```

Answer (score 3):

```
unset IFS
set -f
set +f -- $(<uuid_file)
while  [ "${1+:}" ]
do     : < "$source_directory/$1"*  &&
       printf 'File for %s has arrived.\n' "$2"
       shift 2
done
```

The idea here is not to worry about reporting errors the shell will report for you. If you try to `<` open a file which doesn't exist your shell will complain. In fact, it will prepend your script's `$0` and the line number on which the error occurred to the error output when it does... This is good information that is provided by default already - so don't bother.

You also don't need to take the file in line-by-line like that - it can be awfully slow. This expands the whole thing in a single shot out to a white-space delimited array of arguments and it handles two at a time. If your data is consistent with your example, then `$1` will always be your uuid and `$2` will be your `$name`. If `bash` can open a match to your uuid - and only *one* such match exists - then `printf` happens. Otherwise it doesn't and the shell writes diagnostics to stderr about why.

Comment: @kos - does the file exist? if not, then it behaves as intended. `unset IFS` ensures that `$(cat <uuid_file)` is split on white-space. Shells split on `$IFS`differently when it is comprised of only white-space or is unset. Such split expansions never have any null fields because all white-space sequences stand in as only a single field delimiter. As long as there are only two non-white-space separated fields on each line it should work, i think. in `bash`, anyway. `set -f` ensures that the unquoted expansion is not interpreted for globs, and set +f ensures that the later globs are.

Comment: @kos - i just fixed it. I shouldn't have been using `<>` because that creates a non-existent file. `<` will report as i meant it to. the possible problem with that though - and the reason i incorrectly used `<>` in the first place -  is that if it is a pipe file without a reader or like a line-buffered char dev it will hang. that could be avoided by handling the error output more explicitly and doing `[ -f "$dir/$1"* ]`. we are talking about uuids here, and so it should never expand to more than a single file. it is kinda nice though how it reports the failed files names to stderr like that.

Comment: @kos - actually, i suppose i could use ulimit to keep it from creating any files at all and so `<>` would still be usable that way... `<>` is better if the glob might expand to a directory because on a linux the read/write will fail and say - thats a directory.

Comment: @kos - oh! I'm sorry - im just being dumb - you have two matches, and so its doing the right thing. i mean for it to error in that way if two matches might be had, these are supposed to be uuids - there should never be a possibility of 2 similar names that match the same glob. thats fully intentional - and it *is* ***ambiguous*** in a way that it shouldnt be. you see what i mean? naming the file for a glob isnt the problem, - special chars arent relevant here - the problem is that `bash` will only accept a redirection glob if it only matches one file. see `man bash` under REDIRECTION.

Answer (score 1):

The way I'd approach it is to get uuids from file first, then use `find`

```
awk '{print $1}' listfile.txt  | while read fileName;do find /etc -name "$fileName*" -printf "%p FOUND\n" 2> /dev/null;done
```

For readabilty,

```
awk '{print $1}' listfile.txt  | \
    while read fileName;do \
    find /etc -name "$fileName*" -printf "%p FOUND\n" 2> /dev/null;
    done
```

Example with a list of files in `/etc/`, looking for passwd, group,fstab, and THISDOESNTEXIST filenames.

```
$ awk '{print $1}' listfile.txt  | while read fileName;do find /etc -name "$fileName*" -printf "%p FOUND\n" 2> /dev/null; done
/etc/pam.d/passwd FOUND
/etc/cron.daily/passwd FOUND
/etc/passwd FOUND
/etc/group FOUND
/etc/iproute2/group FOUND
/etc/fstab FOUND
```

Since you've mentioned the directory is flat,you could use the `-printf "%f\n"` option to just print filename itself

What this doesn't do is to list missing files. `find`'s small disadvantage is that it doesn't tell you if it doesn't find a file, only when it matches something. What one could do , however , is to check the output - if the output is empty , then we have a file missing

```
awk '{print $1}' listfile.txt  | while read fileName;do RESULT="$(find /etc -name "$fileName*" -printf "%p\n" 2> /dev/null )"; [ -z "$RESULT"  ] && echo "$fileName not found" || echo "$fileName found"  ;done
```

More readable:

```
awk '{print $1}' listfile.txt  | \
   while read fileName;do \
   RESULT="$(find /etc -name "$fileName*" -printf "%p\n" 2> /dev/null )"; \
   [ -z "$RESULT"  ] && echo "$fileName not found" || \
   echo "$fileName found"  
   done
```

And here's how it performs as a small script:

```
skolodya@ubuntu:$ ./listfiles.sh                                               
passwd found
group found
fstab found
THISDONTEXIST not found

skolodya@ubuntu:$ cat listfiles.sh                                             
#!/bin/bash
awk '{print $1}' listfile.txt  | \
   while read fileName;do \
   RESULT="$(find /etc -name "$fileName*" -printf "%p\n" 2> /dev/null )"; \
   [ -z "$RESULT"  ] && echo "$fileName not found" || \
   echo "$fileName found"  
   done
```

One could use `stat` as alternative, since it's a flat directory, but the code bellow won't work recursively for subdirectories if you ever decide to add those:

```
$ awk '{print $1}' listfile.txt  | while read fileName;do  stat /etc/"$fileName"* 1> /dev/null ;done        
stat: cannot stat ‘/etc/THISDONTEXIST*’: No such file or directory
```

If we take the `stat` idea and run with it, we could use the exit code of stat as indication for whether a file exists or not. Effectivelly, we want to do this:

```
$ awk '{print $1}' listfile.txt  | while read fileName;do  if stat /etc/"$fileName"* &> /dev/null;then echo "$fileName found"; else echo "$fileName NOT found"; fi ;done
```

Sample run:

```
skolodya@ubuntu:$ awk '{print $1}' listfile.txt  | \                                                         
> while read FILE; do                                                                                        
> if stat /etc/"$FILE" &> /dev/null  ;then                                                                   
> echo "$FILE found"                                                                                         
> else echo "$FILE NOT found"                                                                                
> fi                                                                                                         
> done
passwd found
group found
fstab found
THISDONTEXIST NOT found
```